# Parsing SOAP response message java

Tags: java, validation, soap, xpath, rest-assured

I have the following SOAP response message, where I need to validate that the response code is 1, if project import was successful. How can I do this using RestAssured and Java?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<env:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header/>

<env:Body>
    <n1:importProjectResponse 
        xmlns:n1=" some text here......" 
        xmlns:n2="..some text here...." 
        xsi:type="n2:ArrayOfProjectImportResultCode">
        <n2:ProjectImportResultCode>
            <n2:code>1</n2:code>
            <n2:message>Project 'test1' import was successful.</n2:message>
        </n2:ProjectImportResultCode>
    </n1:importProjectResponse>
</env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

I am using RestAssured for testing, and it would be great if I could avoid code bloat by taking advantage of RestAssured instead of writing more classes or methods to do a seemingly simple task. Any ideas?

I tried so far, which of course does not work..

```
response  = given().
    auth().basic(USER, PASSWORD).
    body(request).
    headers("Content-type", "text/xml").
    expect().
        statusCode(200).
        body("//n2:code/text()", is("1")). // does not match .. hmmm :(
    when().post(URL);
```

Comment: So you're using REST and SOAP? Interesting...

Comment: You probably didn't register the namespace. Try `//*[local-name()='code']/text()`

Comment: local-name trick didn't work. I am getting 'XML path //*[local-name()='code']/text() doesn't match.'

Answer (score 0):

This one should work `//*[name()='n2:code']/text()`

Comment: `XML path //*[name()='n2:code']/text() doesn't match.`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer I got from RestAssured support forum was that instead of xpath I could try GPath. That worked for me:

```
response  = given().
auth().basic(USER, PASSWORD).
body(request).
headers("Content-type", "text/xml").
expect().
    statusCode(200).
    body("Envelope.Body.importProjectResponse.ProjectImportResultCode.code[0]", is("1")).
when().post(URL);
```